Finite-rank operator convergence over separable Hilbert space
Suppose I have an operator $A$ on some separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, which might have infinite rank (the rank is defined as the dimension of the range).
In other words, we take an orthonormal basis $\{e_k\}$, and construct the following sequence of operators:
$$A_k = A \Pi_k$$
Where $\Pi_k$ is the projection onto the subspace spanned by the first $k$ elements of the basis.
Does $A_k$ converge to $A$ with respect to the operator norm?
Perhaps this doesn’t work in general, but it might be true with a bounded $A$?

It is not true if $A$ is a noncompact operator. The norm limit of finite dimensional operators is a compact operator.

@RyszardSzwarc ok it makes sense, thanks. But then what happens if $A$ is non-compact? Does $A_k$ still converge to some (compact) operator $A’ \neq A$, or it simply doesn’t converge?

@NYG $A_k$ does not converge at all. In fact, $A_k \to A$ in the strong operator topology, so if $A_k \to B$ in norm for some $B$, we would have $A = B$, which is impossible when $A$ is non-compact. (Also, the result does hold when $A$ is compact, so it’s really an if and only if.)
